# Connecting to SFTP server with Paramiko fails with "An integer is required (got type str)"

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I'm trying to run the following code :

```
#!/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/envs/stg01.nifi_Env/bin/python
import sys
import paramiko
import socket

sftpHost = 'eng-test-host'
sftpPort = '22'
sftpUser = 'user_1'
sftpPass = '123456'
sftpPathSource = '/tmp/poc/'
localPath = '/data/poc/'
sftpIMGFiles = 'test.IMG'


transport=paramiko.Transport((sftpHost, sftpPort))
transport.connect(username=sftpUser, password=sftpPass)
sftp=paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

sftp.put(sftpPathSource + sftpIMGFiles +  localPath + sftpIMGFiles)
sftp.close()
transport.close()

class FastTransport(paramiko.Transport):
    def __init__(self, sock):
        super(FastTransport, self).__init__(sock)
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gettingTtsFile.py", line 18, in <module>
    transport=paramiko.Transport((sftpHost, sftpPort))
  File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 409, in __init__
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect((hostname, port)))
  File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/util.py", line 283, in retry_on_signal
    return function()
  File "/data/go_dl/resources/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 409, in <lambda>
    retry_on_signal(lambda: sock.connect((hostname, port)))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Can someone help me? The Python version that I'm trying to run is 3.8.5 and Paramiko is 2.7.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `port` number arg in the `paramiko.Transport` needs to be an `int` and not `str`

```
sftpHost = 'eng-test-host'
sftpPort = 22 # Note this is int and not str

transport=paramiko.Transport((sftpHost, sftpPort))
```

Comment: omg...in my face and I didn't see..., tried many things but not this, thanks DhakkanCoder.